# Find an inverse of 3 x 3 vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$V_{3}$ is a Vandermonde matrix with $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ all distinct. I've tried looking online but I only found answers such as this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix which is impossible for a first year student like me to understand. Could someone help? Thanks

Comment: Do you know cofactors and how to get the inverse using them? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29